# Validate an uri which contains mustache template with Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm trying to validate an uri which can contains a [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) syntax:

```
{{ key }}
```

So it can look like this (which is an invalid URI in the first place):

```
http(s)://whatever.com/.../{{ key }}/...
```

I'm using `Joi`, it seems that `Joi.string().uri()` cannot allow more letters.
I also checked `Joi.alternatives()` but this would led me to create my own regex which might not be as secure as the one in `Joi`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed no way to augment the internal RFC-compliant regular expression without completely rewriting it.

As you noted, this is an invalid URI *in the first place*. Since you seem to use "simple" Mustache holders and no conditional tags, a workaround would be to provide Joi an already-rendered URI (should we say in the second place then?), something like:

```
const Mustache = require('mustache');
const Joi = require('joi');

// assuming objectToValidate.mustacheString holds a "potentially mustached URI"
/*async */function validateMyStuff(objectToValidate, myJoiSchema) {
  // to catch standard and variable-like tags: {{standard}}, {{{variable}}} or {{&variable}}
  const mustacheTypesToReplace = ['name', '&'];
  // render into the object to validate
  objectToValidate.mustacheString = Mustache.render(
    objectToValidate.mustacheString,
    // build a dummy view object
    Mustache.parse(objectToValidate.mustacheString).reduce((accumulator, parsedItem) => {
      if (mustacheTypesToReplace.includes(parsedItem[0])) {
        accumulator[parsedItem[1]] = 'x'; // dummy data that won't break the RFC
      }
      return accumulator;
    }, {})
  );
  // here the Joi.string().uri() shouldn't break unless URI is wrong
  return Joi.validate(objectToValidate, myJoiSchema).then((validatedObject) => {
    validatedObject.mustacheString = objectToValidate.mustacheString ; // set back the mustached data
    return validatedObject;
  });
}
```